# get error on combineLatest to mapTo

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, redux-observable

```js
export function handleAction(action$) {
    return combineLatest(
                    action$.ofType(actions.LAYOUT_READY),
                action$.ofType(actions.LOADING))
        .mapTo(lastViewedPending())
        .mergeMap((action)=> {
            return leadService.getLastPxls()
                .map(items => lastViewedSucceed(items))
                .startWith(action)
        });
}
```

i am getting error:

```
  TS2345: Argument of type 'LAST_VIEWED_PENDING' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler | LAST_VIEWED_SUCCESS'.
```

Type 'LAST_VIEWED_PENDING' is not assignable to type 'LAST_VIEWED_SUCCESS'.
    Property 'payload' is missing in type 'LAST_VIEWED_PENDING'.

i am using redux-observable

Comment: what is in your lastViewPendingFunction?  I'd be expecting to see map() here rather than mapTo()

Comment: What line is the type error happening? Is it expected that LAST_VIEWED_PENDING doesn't have a `payload` property like LAST_VIEWED_SUCCESS has?